# AWS DAX Node.JS Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Followed the Demo at AWS Demo [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-nodejs.html).

I went through and followed everything step by step. I was able to run their Node.JS files without any errors. However the results I see show 0 improvement between DAX and NON-DAX. Furthermore, after some digging looking at my DAX metrics, the DAX metric charts show 0 Item Cache hits and 0 Item Cache miss even after I execute the 03-GetItem.js  Node.JS application for many times. What the heck is going on? It doesn't seem to be hitting my DAX at all, yet throws no errors.

I ran `aws dax describe-clusters --query "Clusters[*].ClusterDiscoveryEndpoint"`and it successfully returned me the correct cluster address and port # that I am using in the node.js demo apps.

I also verified that the DAX has the IAM priveleges to access all the dynamo tables read and write. 
I also verified DAX and the EC2 are in the same VPC
I also verified that DAX/DDB and EC2 are in the same region.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issues. Essentially the DEMO node.js DAX provided by AWS was using the wrong client. Needed to make a code change for the demo to use daxClient.

https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-dynamodb-developer-guide/issues/3